# Configure Qt Creator for Android development

Tags: android, qt, qt5, qt-creator, android-sdk-tools

I have installed:

**Qt 5.14.1** for msvc 2017 & Android installed to `c:\Qt\Qt5.14.1\`:

[image]

Compilers available in Qt Creator:

[image]

Kits available:
[image]

**JDK-13.0.2** installed to `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2`

**Android Studio 3.6.1** `g:\Android\Android Studio\` with SDKs installed to `g:\Android\SDK` as shown below:

[image]

SDK tools:

[image]

**Now what I see in Qt Creator:**

[image]

How can I fix these errors? Why did they arise?

**Edit:** I've installed JDK 8 instead of 13. But still have the same red crosses.

Also in the topic ['Platform SDK installed' red X Adding Android SDK Tools in Qt Creator](https://forum.qt.io/topic/90310/platform-sdk-installed-red-x-adding-android-sdk-tools-in-qt-creator) says that SDK 25.2.5 has to be installed, **but how can I install SDK 25.2.5 ?** Android Studio doesn't have this version available in the System Settings.

**Edit 2:** I've downloaded the archive "Android SDK Tools 25.2.5" from the link https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/SDKTools . As I understand, this archive contains "SDK tools 25.2.5" + "some Android package manager". Then I:

1. Unpack the archive to the folder `g:\Android\SDK\tools\`. What the folder actually contains:

> ```
> ant\
> apps\
> bin\
> lib\
> lib64\
> proguard\
> qemu\
> support\
> templates\
> android.bat
> ddms.bat
> draw9patch.bat
> hierarchyviewer.bat
> jobb.bat
> lint.bat
> monitor.bat
> monkeyrunner.bat
> traceview.bat
> uiautomatorviewer.bat
> emulator.exe
> emulator-arm.exe
> emulator-check.exe
> emulator-crash-service.exe
> emulator-mips.exe
> emulator-x86.exe
> emulator64-crash-service.exe
> mksdcard.exe
> source.properties
> NOTICE.txt
> package.xml
> ```

2. Run **android.bat** from the folder and in the window that appears, I see that now I have SDK 25.2.5 installed:

[image]

And in Qt Creator Android Settings are almost ok now:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can check these links that may help you. Although, its looks like the problem is the JDK version, you should test with JDK 8, instead the latest release.

- https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Android_known_issues
- https://forum.qt.io/topic/90310/platform-sdk-installed-red-x-adding-android-sdk-tools-in-qt-creator/20

Comment: I've installed JDK 8 instead of 13. But still have the same red crosses.
Also in the topic you have recommended says that SDK 25.2.5 has to be installed, **but how can I install SDK 25.2.5 ?**

Comment: I don't know if this will fix your problem, but older versions of SDK platform-tools can be downloaded clicking in "Show package details" at right bottom, in "SDK Tools" tab.