# Qt creator for Android

Tags: android, qt

I am trying to install Android support in QT Creator, but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnERn.png) is an error that is shown to me. When I click yes, it installs, and when the installation is finished, it shows the same error As you can see, I am using JDK 8, and the latest sdk-tools and ndk from [Google Studio website](https://developer.android.com/studio/)

Any advice?

Comment: Seems you need to install Android SDK Tools 25.2.5 from the link https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/SDKTools. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60641551/4149835

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment, I've wrong tools version.